# Not able to boot OS

Tags: grub, filesystem

I accidentally moved `/etc` to `/home/etc`. I fixed that via putting `init=/bin/bash` in the boot commands, booted, and dropped into a shell with an (initramfs) prompt, where I then did

```
cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda5 sda5
mkdir -p /mnt/sda5
mount /dev/mapper/elementary--root-vg /mnt/sda5
```

and moved `/home/etc` back to `/etc`. Now when I try to boot I get an error along the lines of

```
cannot find file /dev/mapper/elementary--root-vg
```

What would be the next step?

Comment: Why didn't you use a live USB to move it?

Comment: If your issue is resolved, please mark the answer as **Answer** that helped solving your problem. If you have solved this on your own, please write it down as answer and mark it so.